# Angular $scope is not available in the HTML Template but I can see it in console log?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have been following some [online tutorials](http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/) and using the [angularjs-template](https://github.com/pamigomp/angularjs-template) to get started with Angular. I can't get the page (html template) to update with the controller. I think there is a problem with the way I have set up the controller as the values are not available to the html template.

I have been trying to follow some of the best practive guides which suggested to wrap my components in an 'Invoked Function Expression' and to seperate out the controller, service and service manager. However, I think I have made a bit of a hash of this and need some help to figure out what I am doing wrong.

With the console I can see that $scope.metric contains the information I want.  For me this means that the controller has successfully pulled the data back from my API via the metricService. However I can't seem to have the results printed back onto the html page e.g. metric.id.

Any help appreciated - I am at the end of my wits trying to figure this out.

**metric.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-body">
     <!-- Try First Way to Print Results -->
    Id: <span ng-bind="metric.id"></span></br>
    Name:<input type="text" ng-model="metric.metadata.name" /></br>

    <!-- Try Second Way to Print Results -->
    <p data-ng-repeat="thing in ::MEC.metric track by $index">
        {{$index + 1}}. <span>{{thing.metadata.name}}</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </a>
    </p>

<!-- Try Third Way to Print Results -->
    Id: <span ng-bind="Metric.metricId"></span></br>
    Id: <span ng-bind="Metric.id"></span></br>
    Id: <span ng-bind="metricService.id"></span></br>

<!-- Try Fourth Way to Print Results -->
      Id: <strong>{{::MEC.metric.id}}</strong></br>
      Name: <strong>{{::MEC.metric.metadata.name}}</strong></br>
      Height: <strong>{{::MEC.metric.type}}</strong>
</div>
```

**metricController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.metric', ['app.metricService', 'app.metricManager'])    
        .controller('MetricController', MetricController) 

        MetricController.$inject = ['$scope', 'metricManager', '$log'];

        function MetricController($scope, metricManager, $log) {

            metricManager.getMetric(0).then(function(metric) {
                $scope.metric = metric
                $log.info('$scope.metric printed to console below:');
                $log.info($scope.metric);
            })
        }
})();
```

**metricService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.metricService', [])    

    .factory('Metric', ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {  
        function Metric(metricData) {
            if (metricData) {
                this.setData(metricData);
            }
            // Some other initializations related to book
        };

        Metric.prototype = {
            setData: function(metricData) {
                angular.extend(this, metricData);
            },

            delete: function() {
                $http.delete('https://n4nite-api-n4nite.c9users.io/v1/imm/metrics/' + metricId);
            },

            update: function() {
                $http.put('https://n4nite-api-n4nite.c9users.io/v1/imm/metrics/' + metricId, this);
            },

            hasMetadata: function() {
                if (!this.metric.metadata || this.metric.metadata.length === 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                return this.metric.metadata.some(function(metadata) {
                    return true
                });
            }
        };
        return Metric;
    }]);

})();
```

**metricManager.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.metricManager', [])   

    .factory('metricManager', ['$http', '$q', 'Metric', function($http, $q, Metric) {  
    var metricManager = {
        _pool: {},
        _retrieveInstance: function(metricId, metricData) {
            var instance = this._pool[metricId];

            if (instance) {
                instance.setData(metricData);
            } else {
                instance = new Metric(metricData);
                this._pool[metricId] = instance;
            }

            return instance;
        },
        _search: function(metricId) {
            return this._pool[metricId];
        },
        _load: function(metricId, deferred) {
            var scope = this;

            $http.get('https://n4nite-api-n4nite.c9users.io/v1/imm/metrics/' + metricId).then(successCallback, errorCallback)

                function successCallback(metricData){
                    //success code
                    var metric = scope._retrieveInstance(metricData.id, metricData);
                    deferred.resolve(metric);
                };

                function errorCallback(error){
                    //error code
                    deferred.reject();
                }
        },

        /* Public Methods */
        /* Use this function in order to get a metric instance by it's id */
        getMetric: function(metricId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var metric = this._search(metricId);
            if (metric) {
                deferred.resolve(metric);
            } else {
                this._load(metricId, deferred);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        /* Use this function in order to get instances of all the metrics */
        loadAllMetrics: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var scope = this;
            $http.get('ourserver/books')
                .success(function(metricsArray) {
                    var metrics = [];
                    metricsArray.forEach(function(metricData) {
                        var metric = scope._retrieveInstance(metricData.id, metricData);
                        metrics.push(metric);
                    });

                    deferred.resolve(metrics);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    deferred.reject();
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        /*  This function is useful when we got somehow the metric data and we wish to store it or update the pool and get a metric instance in return */
        setMetric: function(metricData) {
            var scope = this;
            var metric = this._search(metricData.id);
            if (metric) {
                metric.setData(metricData);
            } else {
                metric = scope._retrieveInstance(metricData);
            }
            return metric;
        },

    };
    return metricManager;
}]);
})();
```

**Snippet from App.routes**

```
 .state('root.metric', {
                    url: 'metric',
                    data: {
                        title: 'Metric',
                        breadcrumb: 'Metric'
                    },
                    views: {
                        'content@': {
                            templateUrl: 'core/features/metric/metric.html',
                            controller: 'MetricController',
                            controllerAs: 'MEC'
                        }
                    }
                })
```

**Console**
[image]

Comment: What is MEC in `::MEC.metric track by $index"`

Comment: Try `{{::metric}}` and see if you can display matric object

Comment: Can you please show us the ng-controller in the html or the part of the code loading the controller (in routing or others ).

Comment: Yes. When I use {{::metric}} it prints the full text of the JSON object onto the page. The ::MEC is coming from my App.Routes.js file. I added an extract from that to the question above just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two concepts controller alias and $scope, in your case you are creating controller alias as MEC using `controllerAs`. If you are using controller alias then this will work fine for you :

```
function MetricController($scope, metricManager, $log) {
    var MEC = this;
    metricManager.getMetric(0).then(function(metric) {
        MEC.metric = metric
        $log.info('$scope.metric printed to console below:');
        $log.info($scope.metric);
    })
}
```

If you don't want to use controller alias and share data between view and controller via $scope then in your view you should use something like this {{::metric.metadata.name}} and controller function should stay as it is.

PS: If you are using alias then MEC in `var MEC = this` can be MEC or abc or any name you like but convention is to use `var vm = this` and `controllerAs: 'vm'`. If you have controllerAs: 'xyz' then in your view `xyz` should be used to access model.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is working great now. Is using Alias a recommended practice or should I just use $scope without the Alias in my App.routes.

Comment: alias is recommended way, if its working then please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your view HTML, you need to use proper Angular expressions while binding. When you want use ::MEC alias name you need to mark your controller with `as` keyowrd, like `ng-controller="xyz as MEC"`. And checkout working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kMF2yXfEcr1qP5BD9TxA?p=preview)

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!-- Try First Way to Print Results -->
      Id: <span ng-bind="metric.id"></span>
      <br> Name1:
      <input type="text" ng-model="metric.metadata.name" />
      <br><br><br><br>

      <!-- Try Second Way to Print Results -->
      <p data-ng-repeat="thing in [metric] track by $index">
        {{$index + 1}}. <span>{{thing.metadata.name}}</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>

      </p><br><br><br>

      <!-- Try Third Way to Print Results -->
      Id: <span ng-bind="metric.metricId"></span>
      <br> Id: <span ng-bind="metric.id"></span>
      <br><br><br>

      <!-- Try Fourth Way to Print Results -->
      Id: <strong>{{::metric.id}}</strong>
      <br> Name: <strong>{{::metric.metadata.name}}</strong>
      <br> Height: <strong>{{::metric.type}}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for four suggestion. The solution from @ɢʜʘʂʈ ʀɛɔʘɴ solved my problem but I'll look at your plunker in some more detail next.